# Gmaps4Rails V2 setVisible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I think this should be easy but every thing  I try does not work.   What I want to do is add code that hides markers if a review parameter is set.   Unfortunately with Gmaps4Rails V2 I'm having trouble with hiding all markers.

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gmaps4rails/2.1.2/gmaps4rails.js"></script>



</div>

<div style='width: 100%;'>
  <div id="map" style='width: 100%; height: 400px;'></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  if(navigator.geolocation)
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayOnMap);
  markers = handler.addMarkers (<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);

  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();



 _.each(markers, function(index){
   markers[index].hide();
  });


  function displayOnMap(position){
   homepostion = handler.addMarker({
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    lng: position.coords.longitude
  });
  handler.map.centerOn(homepostion);
};
});

</script>
```

As always thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All markers you get from `addMarker` have `show` and `hide` functions [see code](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/gmaps/google/objects/common.coffee#L12-L16)

If you use the clusterer, it's another story, take inspiration from the [removeMarker function](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/gmaps/objects/handler.coffee#L75-L78)

Comment: thanks I tried using  `markers[4].hide();` to test the function without any successes

Comment: thank you very much, that was very helpful unfortunately I'm still not able to solve my problem.   I updated my code with the latest changes.   `_.each(markers, function(index){
   markers[index].hide();
  });` is not working how i would have expected it to

Comment: Yes, sure, look at the way you use _.each